# Magento 2.2.6 - Admin Catalog Products -> Browser freeze

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2.6, product-grid, catalog-product

**Problem**

The admin catalog product overview does load very very very slow (15minutes+) or not at all.

The product overview in the admin loads pretty fast until the animated loading icon appears. So you see the page with the header and menu but no products yet. No 40x or 500 HTTP requests in Chrome or Firefox. The browser simply freezes. No right button response for example.

The server does not show any load when opening the page. Loads up to 0.1x.

After looking for hours and hours, reading and looking for solutions I am lost. Does someone have any idea?

**Background information**

- Magento V2.2.6
- PHP V7.0.27
- My store has about 50k products and 2.5k categories.
- Running on a decent dedicated server (64GB memory) at a specialized Magento hosting
- The frontend and everything else in the admin loads pretty fast. Mostly page load times of 0.x seconds
- Flat catalog and categories is ON
- Minify JS & CSS is ON
- Combining JS & CSS is OFF

Comment: Do you want to try with flat catalog & categories _off_? They don't really provide tangible speed increases in Magento 2

Comment: I'll try and update here when results are in.

Comment: No effect at all. It has not become quicker or slower at all.

Comment: You'll need to run some benchmarking then. Try asking your provider to check for slow logs, if there aren't any then look in to getting XHProf or similar installed on the server

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Contacted the provider. I'll keep this ticket updated when more information is found.

Comment: I had the same issue.
This work for me:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Pages-amp-Products-Admin-Backend-Pages-stuck-on-loader/m-p/99724/highlight/true#M5818